# Using the video editor in ICS for my android application

Tags: android, video, android-intent, trim, video-editing

I have a need for trimming videos before uploading. I was trying (in vain)to figure out some way to use the built in ICS video editor for the same. It looks like the classes for the same are not available as part of sdk. I couldn't find out if there is any way to open editor via some Intent for my purpose. It would be great if I can get some help pointing me in right direction.

Comment: Any luck so far? im trying to find the same thing

Comment: Seems like no go.. dropped that idea for video editor. I couldn't find  such intent :(

Comment: Unfortunate, seems like there isnt really anything built in the system  to do this